# Boolean vs boolean in Java

Tags: java, object, boolean

There are discussions around `Integer` vs `int` in Java. The default value of the former is `null` while in the latter it's `0`. How about `Boolean` vs `boolean`?

A variable in my application can have `0`/`1` values. I would like to use `boolean`/`Boolean` and prefer not to use `int`. Can I use `Boolean`/`boolean` instead?

Comment: For system design reasons I would choose Boolean since it has the option "The user didn't decide yet" which is neither equals with "true", nor "false". I would use boolean primitive only in cases if I am 100% sure true/false options are enough. In database NULL option is usually available without problem (or by just removing NOT NULL restrictions on later demand)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What's the difference between boolean and Boolean in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295170/whats-the-difference-between-boolean-and-boolean-in-java) (because GWT doesn't make a difference).

Answer (score 371, accepted):

**Yes** you can use `Boolean`/`boolean` instead.

First one is Object and second one is primitive type.

- On first one, you will get more methods which will be useful.
- <sub>Second one is cheap considering memory expense</sub>  **The second will save you a lot more memory, so go for it**

Now choose your way.

Comment: You could have phrased this as "the second will save you a lot more memory, so go for it". The useful methods on Boolean can mostly be invoked without having an instance of it.

Comment: As long as you use instead Boolean.valueOf(value) of new Boolean(value), memory shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: for `AsyncTask`, you can only use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Comment: It should be noted the a Boolean actually has 3 states... `true`, `false` and `null` where a boolean has the logical 2 states (`true` and `false`)

Comment: If you plan in putting the boolean inside a collection you need to use Boolean, no other way to do it.

Comment: I think that if I use Boolean and pass that into a method and then its state gets changed by the caller, that change will also be reflected in the method. I have a case where my Boolean is 'connected'. In transports all kinds of things can go bad and one can be in the middle of something and get disconnected. If there is some processing going on in the called method, I want it to know that the state has changed to disconnected. I hope the Boolean will carry that info; I know boolean wont.

Comment: booleans don't safe you any memory over Boolean. Boolean has two constant instances, TRUE and FALSE, they are there regardless if you use a Boolean, or not. A boolean inside of an object is alway as big as the word size of the VM, so it is usually the same size as a reference/pointer to a Boolean. On the stack that might be different. But when it is jitted, it is safe to assume it has the size of a machine word fitting to the CPU. However: for arrays that is very different!.

Answer (score 64):

`Boolean` **wraps** the boolean primitive type. In JDK 5 and upwards, Oracle (or Sun before Oracle bought them) introduced [autoboxing/unboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), which essentially allows you to do this

```
boolean result = Boolean.TRUE;
```

or

```
Boolean result = true;
```

Which essentially the compiler does,

```
Boolean result = Boolean.valueOf(true);
```

So, for your answer, it's YES.

Comment: Note: You can't always safely assign a `Boolean` to a `boolean`. If your `Boolean` is `null` and you try to assign it to a `boolean`, it will throw a `NullPointerException` at runtime.

Comment: if `Boolean` a class then why value is always false even if I changed the value from another class referencing to the same Boolean variable? what is the point of this `Boolean` then if we can't reference to from different instance classes / pass as argument?

Comment: found an answer, we can use `AtomicBoolean` and reference it from difference classes

Answer (score 41):

I am a bit extending provided answers (since so far they concentrate on their "own"/artificial terminology focusing on programming a particular language instead of taking care of the bigger picture behind the scene of *creating the programming languages*, in general, i.e. when things like type-safety vs. memory considerations make the difference):

**int is not boolean**

Consider

```
    boolean bar = true;      
    System.out.printf("Bar is %b\n", bar);
    System.out.printf("Bar is %d\n", (bar)?1:0);
    int baz = 1;       
    System.out.printf("Baz is %d\n", baz);
    System.out.printf("Baz is %b\n", baz);
```

with output

```
    Bar is true
    Bar is 1
    Baz is 1
    Baz is true
```

Java code on 3rd line `(bar)?1:0` illustrates that *bar* (**boolean**) cannot be implicitly converted (casted) into an **int**. I am bringing this up not to illustrate the details of implementation behind JVM, but to point out that in terms of low level considerations (as memory size) one does have to prefer values over type safety. Especially if that type safety is not truly/fully used as in boolean types where checks are done in form of

> if value \in {0,1} then cast to boolean type, otherwise throw an exception.

All just to state that {0,1} < {-2^31, .. , 2^31 -1}. Seems like an overkill, right? Type safety is truly important in user defined types, not in implicit casting of primitives (although last are included in the first).

**Bytes are not types or bits**

Note that in memory your variable from range of {0,1} will still occupy at least a byte or a word (xbits depending on the size of the register) unless specially taken care of (e.g. packed nicely in memory - 8 "boolean" bits into 1 byte - back and forth).

By preferring type safety (as in putting/wrapping value into a box of a particular type) over extra value packing (e.g. using bit shifts or arithmetic), one does effectively chooses writing less code over gaining more memory. (On the other hand one can always define a custom user type which will facilitate all the conversion not worth than Boolean).

**keyword vs. type**

Finally, your question is about comparing *keyword* vs. *type*. I believe it is important to explain why or how exactly you will get performance by using/preferring keywords ("marked" as [primitive](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types)) over types (normal composite user-definable classes using another keyword *class*)
or in other words

```
boolean foo = true;
```

vs.

```
Boolean foo = true;
```

The first "thing" (type) can not be extended (subclassed) and not without a reason. Effectively Java terminology of **primitive** and  **wrapping** classes can be simply translated into **inline** value (a LITERAL or a constant that gets directly substituted by compiler whenever it is possible to infer the substitution or  if not - still fallback into wrapping the value).

Optimization is achieved due to trivial:

> "Less runtime casting operations => more speed."

That is why when the actual type inference is done it may (still) end up in instantiating of wrapping class with all the type information if necessary (or converting/casting into such).

So, the difference between **boolean** and **Boolean** is exactly in **Compilation** and **Runtime** (a bit far going but almost as *instanceof* vs. *getClass()*).

**Finally, autoboxing is slower than primitives**

Note the fact that Java can do [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) is just a "syntactic sugar". It does not speed up anything, just allows you to write less code. That's it. Casting and wrapping into type information container is still performed. For performance reasons choose arithmetics which will always skip extra housekeeping of creating class instances with type information to implement type safety. Lack of *type safety* is the price you pay to gain performance. For code with boolean-valued expressions type safety (when you write less and hence **implicit** code) would be critical e.g. for if-then-else flow controls.

Comment: Incredibly well explained, Yauhen!

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [Boolean constants](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TRUE) - `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` instead of `0` and `1`. You can create your variable as of type `boolean` if primitive is what you are after. This way you won't have to create new `Boolean` objects.

Answer (score 9):

One observation: (though this can be thought of side effect)

**boolean** being a primitive can either say yes or no.

**Boolean** is an object (it can refer to either yes or no or 'don't know' i.e. null)

Answer (score 5):

Basically boolean represent a primitive data type where Boolean represent a reference data type. this story is started when Java want to become purely object oriented it's provided wrapper class concept to over come to use of primitive data type.

```
boolean b1;
Boolean b2;
```

`b1` and `b2` are not same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Boolean / boolean. Simplicity is the way to go.
If you do not need specific api (Collections, Streams, etc.) and you are not foreseeing that you will need them - use primitive version of it (boolean).

1. With primitives you guarantee that you will not pass null values. 
   You will not fall in traps like this. The code below throws NullPointerException (from: [Booleans, conditional operators and autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing)):

   `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Boolean b = true ? returnsNull() : false; // NPE on this line.
       System.out.println(b);
   }
   public static Boolean returnsNull() {
       return null;
   }`
2. Use Boolean when you need an object, eg:

   - Stream of Booleans,
   - Optional
   - Collections of Booleans

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean` is threadsafe, so you can consider this factor as well along with all other listed in answers