# Which statement (true or Boolean.TRUE) will be more efficient

Tags: java

My bean is as below

```
private boolean myBoolean;

public boolean isMyBoolean() {
    return myBoolean;
}

public void setMyBoolean(
        boolean myBoolean) {
    this.myBoolean = myBoolean;
}
```

Now when I use setter for the above Boolean field then what should be the efficient way to do it

```
setMyBoolean(true);
```

or

```
setMyBoolean(Boolean.TRUE);
```

I know that autoboxing will take care and both will work But I don't know what is the efficient way in this example. So my question is which of both should I use to write an efficient code OR both are equally good

TIA

Comment: Go through this answer[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java]

Comment: Another previous post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911563/java-performance-true-vs-boolean-true

Comment: You can safely assume the tools you use are not horribly broken, at least until they prove otherwise.

Comment: If you really care about performance for this code, compare them by profiling their runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*imho*

```
 setMyBoolean(true);
```

Primitives  always do favor than Wrappers.Where ever I am able to use primitives,I go for them

Because while run time, If we use Wrappers [Boxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.7)  and [Unboxing Conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.8) happens at Runtime,Obviously that takes more time.

In your case

At run time, boxing conversion proceeds as follows:

If p is a value of type `boolean`, then boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of class and type Boolean, such that `r.booleanValue() == p`

If you use primitive there,Obviously you save that time.

Answer (score 4):

Use the first one. More readable. You don't need to concern about the performance issue here, although the second one will involve auto-boxing and comparatively slower (again, you don't need to think about it).

Only consider code readability in this type of cases, and remember that primitives will always be faster than objects.

Comment: +1 simplicity and clarity is not only more important 9 times out of 10 is usually the fastest or fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

The reason

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;
```

works is because of *autounboxing*, a Java 5 feature that allows a wrapper object to be converted to its primitive equivalent automatically when needed

**as you can understand, setting is faster then autounboxing and then setting...**

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter. At the very end when your code is compiled the bytecode generated will end up using the boolean data type on the JVM.

What I am trying to say is, on compile time, such a simple code like this will be optimized automatically for the JVM. It does not matter which way you use, remember that the compiler will end up translating this into bytecode and JVMs nowadays do this kind of optimizations all the time.

If you are skeptical on this, you can try both ways and use a profiler on your code. You will be amazed.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean.TRUE` is a wrapper object for `boolean`.

Boolean class implementation from Sun SDK:

```
public final class Boolean ... 
{
    private final boolean value;

    public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
    public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
    ...
}
```

when you use `setMyBoolean(Boolean.TRUE);`:

1. VM creates Boolean  object (in heap) and the saves the `value` to true.
2. Unboxes the created object and finally assigns primitive `true` to `myboolean`.

when you use `setMyBoolean(true);`: only step 2 will be performed from above. Thus faster!