# When should I use Boolean instead of boolean?

Tags: java

When should I use Boolean instead of boolean?. I mean, why would I want to have a null value in a variable which should contain either "true" or "false".. One spontaneous answer (of most people) would be if the value is unknown. i.e, if we don't know whether the value is true or false. But from a programming perspective, I think using Boolean may break the code as we will not know whats inside. So, I think using the primitive type is better than the wrapper.. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Most people's spontaneous answer is your answer here.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate close; that question is misnamed and is asking more about `boolean` vs. `int`.

Comment: (Another) Answer to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705497/6931119 Could not answer against this post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking, the wrapper classes are used in cases where an object is required or strongly preferred. Outside of these situations, it's better to use the primitive types, since they have lower overhead, you can use `==`, etc. There are two and a half major situations where this is frequently seen:

- Collections. This is now a subset of the next case, but even before Java 5 the Collections classes only supported objects as keys and values, and this hasn't changed.
- Generics. Generic types can only work with objects, not primitives, and so if you're using "boolean" as a type parameter, it has to be the wrapper class. For example, if you're using a `Future`, you have to use a `Boolean` instead of a `boolean`. (HT @user949300)
- ORM. JPA and other ORM systems technically can use primitive fields, but it's customary to use the wrapper classes, since the overhead is high enough that that doesn't really matter anyway, and the wrapper classes can represent a `NULL` value that might be present in the database. It's usually still better to forbid nulls and use a primitive for booleans, though, since semantically a default is usually better than "undefined".

Since boolean values are restricted to either `true` or `false`, it's uncommon to see them used in Collections or Generics; generally speaking, if you'd have a boolean as a value, you'll just use `Collection#contains` instead.

Comment: +1 Good point on the Generics.  Example if a long running process (Future) needs to return a true/false, it must return a Boolean, not a boolean.

Answer (score 11):

*IMHO* the primitive is better.

Always favor primitives over wrappers. Wherever I am able to use primitives, I go for them because at run time, if we use wrappers, [boxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) and [unboxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.8) happen, and obviously that takes more time. If you use the primitive there, you save that time.

And as usual it depends on your requirements whether you need a `Object` (which can be `null`) or you can use a primitive (which cannot be `null`) in your situation.

For example: Assume you are dealing with collection's then you have no option's,You have to use wrappers :).

Comment: What if you need `null`? That should be the only consideration. "Saving time or memory" is a non-issue with Boolean, which only has two static instances that are already created before your program even starts running.

Comment: @Thilo True. That is why I used the term Object which can be `null`.

Comment: Agree with @Thilo.  While there are good reasons for preferring primitives over wrappers, performance is seldom an issue, especially with Booleans.  Don't understand why this answer is getting all the votes.

Comment: @user949300 No issues,I pointed why to go for primitives and as well as when to go for wrappers.Please feel free to down vote if you are not satisfied with this,I'm with you. :)

Comment: The program I have written is something like this... if(boolean_val) do {something} , else { do someOtherThing.. }.. Now, to add boolean values to collections, I changed them to Boolean, now, the problem is I have 3 cases (true, false and null) and I have to handle the "null" case as well.. And I feel it makes no sense to check for null values.. imagine having hundreds of Boolean values and adding lines like if(val is null)

Comment: @X86 Then write a small util method.Such that  that method takes takes a collection object and Boolean object as parameters.There check null/or any conditions there and add to that collection.So you should not duplicate your code.

Comment: @X86 Don't write those utility methods. Use Commons-Lang [`BooleanUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#line.32) instead. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Boolean have 3 possible values (null, true, false) while boolean can only be (true, false).

Answer (score 3):

I greatly prefer primitives.  However, Booleans are necessary:

1. When they go into Collections
2. When you need to allow for a null value.  In my experience, this is mainly if they are stored in a database and you need null to indicate that they haven't been read yet, or the user hasn't filled in some form yet.

Answer (score 0):

What if you need to use collections?
Collection will not store primitive types, you need to store object there.
Collections provide so many utility apis, so if you want to use them them a Boolean object is need as collection will need objects.
Although you can always use autoboxing which means you are shielded from object creation and collection takes care of it internally.

Answer (score 0):

The Wrapper classes will be in cases where an object is required or strongly preferred like storing the objects in Collections, cache or session etc, where it requires an object (if not, JRE will convert the primitives to Wrapper classes before they are stored in secondary cache). The below link will explain in better:

[Boolean vs boolean in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean` is an object, so you can use it with generics. For example, you can have `Map<String,Boolean>` to store a true\false value for each string(=key). You can't do `Map<String,boolean>`, because `boolean` is not an object - specifically, it's not a subclass of `Object`. Generics are compile-time wrappers, so `Map<Foo,Bar>` is actually `Map<Object,Object>` with smart casting, no matter what `Foo` and `Bar` are - as long as they are classes or array types. But they can't be primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Booolean is an object/reference type that wraps a boolean whereas boolean in a primitive type.

**Boolean** - You would get more methods which will be useful.

**boolean** - Will save you lot of memory. But if you use `Boolean.valueOf(value) of new Boolean(value)`, that shouldn't be a cause.

Converting between primitives and objects like this is known as boxing/unboxing.

Click on the below links for more info:

http://javaeye.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/boxing-and-unboxing-conversion/

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197