# For boolean fields in Java Model class is it better to use Boolean object or primitive boolean field

Tags: java

For boolean fields in Java Model class is it better to use Boolean object or primitive boolean

What are the best use cases for each of them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java

Comment: If the field should be able to hold `null`, use `Boolean`, if not, use `boolean`.

Comment: If the field should be able to hold `null`, it's not really a boolean at all.  Consider an `enum`, or perhaps the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class (available in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) before Java 8).