# Are wrappers of a primitive type primitives types too?

Tags: java, types

I'm confused about data types in Java. I've seen a lot of images on the Internet representing the data types in Java as a tree that makes me hesitate about what I used to think about it. An example of those trees are shown as follows: [image: Figure 1: Java data types schema.]

So, in another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java), Buhake Sindi's points that:

> Boolean is a wrapper of a primitive type

Following the previous tree representation of data types in Java, my questions are:

1. A wrapper of a primitive data type is a primitive data type too? For example *Boolean*, *Integer*, *Character*.
2. Where should be the *Object* data type in the tree? As I understand, *Object* is a memory region that can contain any type in Java; from primitives to classes created by the programmer. So, *Object* may contain both primitive and non-primitive data types. Is that true?

Comment: ... Wrappers wrap primitives. They're not primitives. Primitives are explicitly not objects; that's why they're called primitives, and why they have wrappers. The object hierarchy provided shows that the primitive wrappers have their own inheritance tree. Noting that not everything under the "Primitive" header is actually a class name--but some are, which makes it a poorly-designed document.

Comment: Wrappers are objects, not primitives, but they may get unboxed to primitives as needed .

Comment: No that diagram is misleading: the leafs are primitives, above are wrappers of primitives - "Numeric" and "Floating-point" are no classes too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, wrappers for primitives aren't primitives. That's the point of them: They're used to *wrap* primitives when an object reference is required instead of a primitive (such as in a `List`).

In that tree graphic, "Boolean" and "Integer" aren't class/type names, they're just labels (like "Floating-point" is).

`Object` fits into that tree at the top of "Non-Primitive".

So for instance, the wrappers would be under non-primitive types:

```
               Data Type
                 /    \
                /      \
               /        \
              /          \
      Primitive Types    Non-Primitive Types (base class: Object)
            /                         /                  \
           /                         /                    \
    Numeric Types         Primitive Wrapper Types         (etc.)
         /                    /      |      \
        /                    /       |       \
  Integer Types           Char    Integer  Boolean
      /
     /
   char
```

(Obviously that's very incomplete.)

> As I understand, `Object` is a memory region that can contain any type in Java; from primitives to classes created by the programmer.

No, it's not a memory region. It's a type.

> So, `Object` may contain both primitive and non-primitive data types.

No, a variable, instance member, or parameter of type `Object` (or any of its subtypes) can only contain an object reference, not a primitive like `int` or `char`. That's *why* we have wrappers for primitives, so we can store them (via a wrapper) where an object reference is expected.

---

Also note that the diagram is misleading in another way: "Floating Point" shouldn't be under "Integral." In computer science, "integral types" are **integers** (in mathematics, it's more complex than that). Which is why the JLS splits *NumericType* into *IntegralType* and *FloatingPointType* ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)).

**And** `char` is an [integral type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-IntegralType) in Java.

---

FWIW, my rough pass at that sketch would look something like this:

[image]

The final would hopefully be less squashed and ugly. :-) Note that I'm repeating "Types" everywhere to avoid the appearance of using class names, and I've used typeface (like your original did) to call out when I'm using keywords or class names.

Comment: so why can I do something like: int a = 4; Object x = a;? If an Object variable can contain only an object reference that would be throw an error

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez there is some [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) happening in that case behind the scenes. `a` is _wrapped_ to `Integer` and that's why you don't get any Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The graphic is confusing because it mixes up terminology.

The "Non-Primitive" branch shows classnames (`String`, `Array`, etc.) while the "Primitive" branch mixes actual classnames with labels, e.g., `Boolean` and `Integer` are classes, but used here as node labels. "Floating-point" is not a class, only a label.

Wrapper classes wrap primitives, e.g., the `Boolean` class wraps the `boolean` primitive.

Answer (score 1):

**1. *A wrapper of a primitive data type is a primitive data type too? For
    example Boolean, Integer, Character.***

No. Wrapper of a primitive is not a primitive data type. Are objects which wraps the primitive types. So the diagram is misleading because it places the wrapper classes under the primitive section and should be under the non-primitive section.

**2. *Where should be the Object data type in the tree? As I understand,
        Object is a memory region that can contain any type in Java; from
        primitives to classes created by the programmer. So, Object may
        contain both primitive and non-primitive data types. Is that true?***

Object is not a memory region. *"[`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class"*. It should be the first element under the non-primitive section of the diagram.