# Runtime error and what constructor should I have to build in class Pet?

Tags: java, class, runtime

So as I understand, Goat class has no problem with a code,
I want to assign the first two elements from a new object, but I am not sure why it gives an runtime error

```
class Pet {
    public String name;
    public boolean indoor;

    public Pet(String name, Boolean indoor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.indoor = indoor;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return name + ", " + indoor; 
    }
}

class Goat extends Pet {
    public int age;
    public String diet;
    public Goat(String name, boolean indoor, int age, String diet) {
         super(name, indoor);
         this.age = age;
         this.diet = diet;
    }
```

Here is the test code and error

[image: test code & error]}

Comment: your ```public Pet(String name, Boolean indoor)``` takes a Boolean object, instead of boolean . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java

Comment: You seem to have compiled Goat against the Pet class you're showing us, but to be running the test with a different version of the Pet class.

Comment: this code runs fine... can you provide the test code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is being thrown because, Pet class constructor is expecting Boolean and Goat class constructor  is passing boolean. Although compiler is compiling code, but at runtime java is not able to find boolean  type constructor. Hence, throwing no method error.

Correct Code will be

```
class Pet {
    public String name;
    public boolean indoor;

    public Pet(String name, boolean indoor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.indoor = indoor;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return name + ", " + indoor; 
    }
}

class Goat extends Pet {
    public int age;
    public String diet;
    public Goat(String name, boolean indoor, int age, String diet) {
         super(name, indoor);
         this.age = age;
         this.diet = diet;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved a problem! I thought Boolean and boolean works equally, hahaha. Unexpected to get this!

Comment: As you mentioned, it solved your problem. Don't know why you down-voted the answer.