# Java hibernate No validator could be found for boolean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, annotations

I have a service method that tries to add an object with `store()` method of hibernate. get method is working for this DAO and service class whereas adding not working. In console there is no error.

```
UrlWhiteListDaoImpl urlDao;

MapperFacade mapper;

@Autowired
public UrlWhiteListingServiceImpl(UrlWhiteListDao urlWhiteListDao, MapperFacade mapper, UrlWhiteListDaoImpl urlDao) {
    this.urlDao = urlDao;
    this.urlWhiteListDao = urlWhiteListDao;
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

@Override
public UrlWhiteListDto addUrlWhiteListItem(UrlWhiteListDto urlWhiteListDto) throws Exception {
    String domainUrlToBeAdded = parseUrl(urlWhiteListDto.getDomain());
    if (isDomainExistbyName(domainUrlToBeAdded)) {
        throw new Exception("Already existed domain is tried to be added");
    }
    UrlWhitelist urlModel = mapper.map(urlWhiteListDto,UrlWhitelist.class);
    urlDao.store(urlModel);
    return urlWhiteListDto;
```

}

My model class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = UrlWhitelist.TABLE_NAME)
public class UrlWhitelist implements EntityBean { 

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "URL_WHITE_LIST";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "DOMAIN", nullable = false)
    private String domain;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "DISABLE", nullable = false)
    private boolean disabled;

    // getters & setters omitted
}
```

And DAO implementation class is:

```
public class UrlWhiteListDaoImpl extends EntityDaoImpl<UrlWhitelist, Long> implements UrlWhiteListDao {

    protected UrlWhiteListDaoImpl() {
        super(UrlWhitelist.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UrlWhitelist> getByDomainName(String name) {
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UrlWhitelist.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("domain", name));
        return getAllByCriteria(criteria);
    }
}
```

In console there is no error but in server log it says:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [services] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.Boolean'. Check configuration for 'disabled'] with root cause
>       javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.Boolean'. Check configuration for 'disabled'

I thought there is something wrong with mapping between to and model class, but, then why get method is working and only `store()` is not working? What is the solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [`@NotNull`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) annotation.

Your `boolean` is a primitive type, not an object type (`Boolean`) hence the constraint [`@NotNull`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) cannot be applied since the primitive type cannot be `null`. The annotation performs the following validation (formatting added by me):

> The annotated element must not be `null`. Accepts any type.

Use the object type:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "DISABLE", nullable = false)
private Boolean disabled;
```

Comment: thank you very much. yes it is working like as you said, but, i need a primitive type, what can i do about changing dto class without touching model class ?(like not defining it as notnull etc.) if it is not possible then i can change model class.

Comment: Why do you need a primitive type? The primitive type is by default `false` and might be `true` is set. If you restrict the `Boolean` to be not `null`, it behaves the same. Moreover, you can work with `Boolean` the same as it is a `boolean`.

Comment: by the way i have dto class also. does it matter boolean or Boolean in my dto class ?

Comment: Nope, it really doesn't matter. See [Boolean vs. boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java).

Comment: by the way it did not work. i thought it works when i change model class boolean to Boolean but not. and there is no error message.

Comment: What does mean "it didn't work". What error message is shown?

Comment: same error: 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [services] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.Boolean'. Check configuration for 'disabled']

Comment: remember changing NotBlank to NotNull and boolean to Boolean, because in the message I am still seeing 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank'

Answer (score 1):

to solve this error you MUST use correct annotations. In the above problem, `@NotBlank` annotation must be applied to any String field only.

To validate boolean type field, use annotation `@NotNull` or use `Boolean` boxed type

Answer (score 0):

```
If(Boolean.TRUE.equals(disabled)){

//If you check this type of any Boolean value then check null value and also false both field}
```