# Declaring boolean variable

Tags: java, android

I just saw a code from another developer.

```
private static boolean _menuNeedsUpdate = false;
private static Boolean _userIsLoggingIn = Boolean.valueOf(false);
```

I want to know the differences between these two declarations. Can any one please clarify this?

Comment: One is a Java "primitive type" (boolean), the other is a Java "class" (Boolean).  You can read more about "Wrapper classes" (such as "Boolean") here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class

Comment: The main practical difference is that `Boolean` can be set to null when `boolean` can not.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou  `I want to know the differences between these two declarations.`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I believe the intention is to discover why developer declared first variable as primitive and second as wrapper.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ nevertheless, since those variables are not `final` it's probably a useful information for the OP to be aware of the possible `null` state of the non-primitive `Boolean`.

Comment: @Carsten null in `Boolean` can be used in meaning "undefined", which is sometimes very useful.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Which is, third possibility of a boolean :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a primitive `boolean` with default value `false`.

The second one is a [Wrapper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) of `Boolean` with default value `false`.

Apart, I can't see any more difference.

**Edit :** (Thankyou @carsten @sasha)

Apart from the declaration, another point worth mentioning is with the second declaration the value of `_userIsLoggingIn`  may become `null` later on where as the primitive cannot.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there is some memory consumption related differences.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use Boolean/boolean instead.

First one is Object and second one is primitive type

On first one, you will get more methods which will be useful

Second one is cheap considering memory expense.

Now choose your way

Answer (score 2):

Frist one is java primitive and second one is an object/refrence types that wraps a boolean.

Converting between primitives and objects like this is known as boxing/unboxing.

- boolean can be yes or no.
- Boolean can be yes, no or NULL.

Answer (score 0):

**boolean** is a literal true or false, while **Boolean** is an object wrapper for a boolean.

There is seldom a reason to use a Boolean over a boolean except in cases when an object reference is required, such as in a List.

Boolean also contains the static method parseBoolean(String s), which you may be aware of already.

More info :
[What's the difference between boolean and Boolean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295170/whats-the-difference-between-boolean-and-boolean-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As others said, the first declaration is a primitive while the second is wrapper class.

I would like to add that the second declaration creates a warning when using Java 5 or newer. 
Declaring `_userIsLoggingIn` like

```
private static Boolean _userIsLoggingIn = false;
```

instead of

```
private static Boolean _userIsLoggingIn = Boolean.valueOf(false);
```

will use `Boolean.FALSE`, avoiding the creation of a new Boolean instance